# Manage who connects to a ClickOnce Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, deployment, clickonce

I've published a WPF application with ClickOnce with internet connection required.

**Is there any way to control who can connect to the application?**

Let's say the app needs a subscription system to be used, and if the client doesn't pay, the application can't start.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/aa480721(v=msdn.10) ?

Comment: @RubensFarias That's what I was looking for, I truly couldn't find it. If you put it as an answer I will mark it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [Administering ClickOnce Deployments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/aa480721(v=msdn.10))

Even though there are no built-in mechanisms with ClickOnce to determine which users are trying to deploy your applications, there are a number of approaches you can employ to obtain this information. These include:

- Windows authentication over HTTP(S).
- Custom authentication designed
  into the application.
- Passing query string parameters when launching
  the application (requires dynamic manifest generation with embedded
  user credentials for installed applications).
- Custom client proxy and
  custom HTTP module authentication.

I ended up choosing Custom Authentification methods to control who can enter or not into my application.